# Cube Js | calculate difference between 2 Dates

Tags: javascript, mysql, cubes, analytical, cube.js

In cube js finding the count between days is not working for mysql database. Please help me  to resolve. While calculating the balance days between....

```
measures: {
  balanceDays: 
    {
      type: count,
      sql: DATEDIFF(day, '${NmOrder.show_date}', '${NmOrder.booked_date}')   
    },
},
```

This is also not working

```
measures: {
      balanceDays: 
        {
          type: count,
          sql: TO_DAYS(${show_date}) - TO_DAYS(${booked_date}) 
        },
    },
```

Comment: @RobG no. Please check once again my question. i made some changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to mention MySQL keywords. Just simply like below

```
measures: {
      balanceDays: 
        {
          type: countDistinct,
          sql: show_date - booked_date 
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
measures: {
      balanceDays: 
        {
          type: `number`,
          sql: `DAY(${show_date} - ${booked_date})` 
        }
    },
```